# OpenJPA Enhance -- The identity field defined in the {0} Embeddable is not supported

Tags: java, mysql, jpa, openjpa

I am using the following JPA code with MySQL DB and OpenJPA 2.2.2:

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class IdentifiableEntity implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    // getters, setters, etc.
}

@Entity
public class User extends IdentifiableEntity {
    private String name;

    // getters, setters, etc.
}
```

I get this message when doing `User user = new User();` in JSE environment:

> ERROR  [main] openjpa.Enhance - The identity field defined in the
>   IdentifiableEntity Embeddable is not supported.

I tried running with the OpenJPA dynamically loaded class enhancer on Oracle 1.6 JDK. The code seems to be executing correctly in spite of the message.

Why am I getting this message? Is it benign?

Here are the contents of `persistence.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="2.0"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
 <persistence-unit name="persistenceUnit">
    <provider>org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceProviderImpl</provider>
    <properties>
      <property name="openjpa.ConnectionURL"
        value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/playground?useUnicode=true&amp;characterEncoding=UTF-8"/>
      <property name="openjpa.ConnectionDriverName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
      <property name="openjpa.ConnectionUserName" value="guest"/>
      <property name="openjpa.ConnectionPassword" value="guest"/>

      <!-- Classes should be enhanced at build-time for production. -->
      <property name="openjpa.RuntimeUnenhancedClasses" value="unsupported"/>
      <property name="openjpa.DynamicEnhancementAgent" value="true"/>

      <!-- Enable logging -->
      <property name="openjpa.Log" value="DefaultLevel=WARN, Runtime=INFO, Tool=INFO, SQL=TRACE" />
      <property name="openjpa.ConnectionFactoryProperties" value="PrintParameters=true" />
    </properties>
 </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Comment: Do you have an @Embeddable annotation somewhere?  The error message seems to suggest that you do.

Comment: No `Embeddable` annotation. I'm guessing `Embeddable` is implied because I'm using a `MappedSuperclass`.

Comment: Can you post the contents of your persistence.xml, and is there an exception logged with the ERROR?

Answer (score 0):

Have the same error. After some debugging I found out that the lines which print it out are from the patch for: [OPENJPA-2233](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/OPENJPA-2233). It also changes condition to add pcNewObjectIdInstance, but it doesn't affect MappedSuperclass objects.

I think we shouldn't bother. I'll create an issue on apache JIRA.

Comment: Can you provide a link to the JIRA issue?

Comment: More than one year later I accidentally find this comment (never got any notification), but the issue is still open so I'll give you the link: [OPENJPA-2396](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/OPENJPA-2396).

Answer (score 0):

Having the same problem with OpenJpa 2.2.2.

Its something related to the persistence.xml - when I enhance my entities with a persistence.xml configured for HSqlDb then everything works.  When I use a persistence.xml configured for MySql Cluster it bombs out with that error.  So it seems something in the persistence.xml triggers another path in the code during enhancement that just doesn't work.

Will come back and comment if I figure out something useful.

My persistence.xml with both configurations

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" version="2.0">
  <persistence-unit name="testdb" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceProviderImpl</provider>
    <class>code.TestDataBean</class>
    <class>code.shared.DataBean</class>
    <class>code.shared.AbstractDataBean</class>
    <properties>
      <!-- HSqlDb -->
      <!--
      <property name="openjpa.jdbc.SynchronizeMappings" value="buildSchema" />
      <property name="openjpa.ConnectionURL" value="jdbc:hsqldb:testdb" />
      <property name="openjpa.ConnectionDriverName" value="org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver" />
      <property name="openjpa.ConnectionUserName" value="sa" />
      <property name="openjpa.ConnectionPassword" value="" />
      <property name="openjpa.Log" value="DefaultLevel=TRACE" />
      -->
      <!-- MySql Cluster port 5000 -->
      <property name="openjpa.jdbc.SynchronizeMappings" value="buildSchema" />
      <property name="openjpa.ConnectionDriverName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
      <property name="openjpa.ConnectionURL" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:5000/clusterdb" />
      <property name="openjpa.ConnectionUserName" value="root" />
      <property name="openjpa.ConnectionPassword" value="" />
      <property name="openjpa.BrokerFactory" value="ndb" />
      <property name="openjpa.jdbc.DBDictionary" value="TableType=ndb"/>
      <property name="openjpa.ndb.connectString" value="localhost:1186" />
      <property name="openjpa.ndb.database" value="clusterdb" />
      <property name="openjpa.Log" value="DefaultLevel=TRACE" />
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Comment: You did mention the code seems to be working irregardless.  I got the error when enhancing, but running the process again does tell me that the entities have already been enhanced.  So it doesn't seem like the error is aborting the whole enhancement process.

Comment: My follow-up, but not yet resolved and probably more MySql Cluster specific than your issue: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/OPENJPA-2407